# Dúvida - Winforms sobre a respeito na segunda tela

Tags: c#, winforms

Form1 criei panel com fundo preto e label com propriedade:

- AutoSize = False
- Dock = Fill
- Tamanho da letra(Size) = 20
- E 2 botões para avançar ou voltar letras

Form2 só tem form preto e um label com propriedade:

- AutoSize = False
- Dock = Fill
- Tamanho da letra(Size) = 40

Segue código como eu mostro na segunda tela(monitor):

```
telaSecundaria = new SegundaTela();
Screen[] telas = Screen.AllScreens;
Rectangle bounds = telas[1].Bounds; // pode ser outro índice.
telaSecundaria.SetBounds(bounds.X, bounds.Y, bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
telaSecundaria.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
telaSecundaria.Show();
telaSecundaria?.ChangeLabel(label.Text);
```

Maior problema é a resolução de monitor, fiz teste de vários monitores aqui e são tudo diferente. As letras não são a mesma do Form1, exemplo:

No Form1:

> Todo mundo quer ser legal, e todo mundo se ferra na empreitada. É
>   difícil ser legal o tempo inteiro. A gente consegue ser legal a maior
>   parte do tempo, mas aí faz uma besteira e pronto: tudo o que você fez
>   de bom é imediatamente esquecido e você se torna apenas aquele que fez
>   a grande besteira. Aí você precisa de mais uns dois meses sendo
>   exclusivamente legal para todo mundo esquecer da besteira. E quando
>   eles esquecem, você faz outra, claro.

No Form2(monitor):

> Todo mundo quer ser legal, e todo mundo se ferra na empreitada. É
>   difícil ser
>            legal o tempo inteiro. A gente consegue ser legal a maior
>   parte do tempo, mas
>    aí faz uma besteira e pronto: tudo o que você fez
>   de bom é imediatamente
>      esquecido e você se torna apenas aquele que fez
>   a grande besteira. Aí você
>       precisa de mais uns dois meses sendo
>   exclusivamente legal para todo mundo
>      esquecer da besteira. E quando
>   eles esquecem, você faz outra, claro.

Como posso corrigir as posições de cada palavra ? Aqui no monitor e a tela do cliente está ok. O problema é monitor diferente (resolução diferente). Eu quero que Form2 fica a mesma do Form1.

Segue a foto (cliente):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E do monitor:

https://s1.postimg.org/5gyzn0lc6n/20171109_212331.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz um código pra ajustar a fonte do label automaticamente pelo tamanho do Form, veja se funciona e depois comento o código explicando tudo

```
  Timer tSize = new Timer() { Interval = 300, Enabled = false };
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = @"Todo mundo quer ser legal, e todo mundo se ferra na empreitada. É difícil ser legal o tempo inteiro. A gente consegue ser legal a maior parte do tempo, mas aí faz uma besteira e pronto: tudo o que você fez de bom é imediatamente esquecido e você se torna apenas aquele que fez a grande besteira. Aí você precisa de mais uns dois meses sendo exclusivamente legal para todo mundo esquecer da besteira. E quando eles esquecem, você faz outra, claro."; 

        tSize.Tick +=  (s,arg) => {
             ((Timer)s).Enabled = false;
             SetLabelSize();
        };
    }


    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tSize.Enabled = false;
        tSize.Enabled = true;
    }
    private void label1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tSize.Enabled = false;
        tSize.Enabled = true;
    }
    private void SetLabelSize()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        label1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        label1.AutoSize = true;
        label1.MaximumSize = new Size(this.Width, 0);
        label1.Font = new Font("Consolas", 12);
        float size = label1.Font.Size;
        int limite = this.Height - 30;
        while (label1.Height < limite- label1.Font.Height)
        {
            size += 0.1f;
            label1.Font = new Font("Consolas", size);
        }

        this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }
```

**Edit:**

Conforme pedido, para manter a tela (label) na proporção 4:3 basta trocar algumas linhas no código.

Remova: `label1.MaximumSize = new Size(this.Width, 0);`

e coloque:

```
label1.MaximumSize = new Size(this.Height + this.Height /4 , 0);
panel2.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding((panel2.Width - label1.Width) / 2, 0, 0, 0);
```

Onde panel2 é onde o label está inserido. Ou seja, é o Parent do label.

Resultado:

> Coloquei o label com fundo de outra cor para diferenciar do form.

[image: Form Pequeno]

[image: Form Grande]

[image: Tela Cheia (1920x1080)]

Comment: pode até deixar no form, só trocar `panel2` por `this`

Comment: ser tela secundária não importa. Deixou passar algo