# Como verificar se a linha foi quebrada?

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu uso `File.ReadAllText` para ler o texto dentro de um arquivo `.txt`.

```
private void label9_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = File.ReadAllText($@"{pathname}", Encoding.UTF8);

    if (text.Length) // Como fazer aqui ?
    {

    }    
}
```

Dentro do meu arquivo `.txt` tem:

```
Pois diga que irá 
Irá já, Irajá
Pra onde eu só veja você,
Você veja-me só
Marajó, Marajó
Qualquer outro lugar comum, outro lugar qualquer
Guaporé, Guaporé.
Qualquer outro lugar ao sol, outro lugar ao sul.
Céu azul, céu azul.
Onde haja só meu corpo nu
Junto ao seu corpo nu
```

No formulário eu tenho `label1` e `panel1`. O resultado do label:

```
Pois diga que irá 
Irá já, Irajá
Pra onde eu só veja você,
Você veja-me só
Marajó, Marajó
Qualquer outro lugar comum, outro 
lugar qualquer
Guaporé, Guaporé.
Qualquer outro lugar ao sol, outro 
lugar ao sul.
Céu azul, céu azul.
Onde haja só meu corpo nu
Junto ao seu corpo nu
```

Pode ver que na sexta e nona linha foi quebrada automaticamente, como posso saber se algumas dessas linhas foi quebrada ? Se sim, diminuir a fonte.

Na sexta linha ela deve ficar dessa forma:

```
Qualquer outro lugar comum, outro lugar qualquer
```

Na nona linha ela deve ficar dessa forma:

```
Qualquer outro lugar ao sol, outro lugar ao sul
```

Deve respeitar de acordo com arquivo `.txt`.

Comment: coloca seu código

Comment: havia feito um código parecido... fui ver, e foi pra você também kkkk acho que pode te atender também nessa questão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/254130/69359

Comment: Parecido, mais essa deve respeitar de acordo com `.txt`  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente basta você verificar se o espaço do texto será maior que a largura do label, e enquanto for, vai diminuindo a fonte.

Para isso, você utiliza o `MeasureString` da classe `Graphics` e um `while`, que vai diminuindo a fonte enquanto o `Width` do texto for maior que o do `label`.

Código de exemplo:

```
private void label1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
    float p = 14;
    Font f = new Font(((Label)sender).Font.Name, p);
    SizeF s = g.MeasureString(((Label)sender).Text, f);

    while (s.Width >= ((Label)sender).Width - 20)
    {
       p = p - 0.1f;
       f = new Font(((Label)sender).Font.Name, p);
       s = g.MeasureString(((Label)sender).Text, f);
    }

    ((Label)sender).Font = f;
}
```

> Resultado:
>   [image: Resultado:]

Comment: O que é `float p = 14;` ?

Comment: é o tamanho da fonte inicial, seria a maior fonte possível se couber na label

Comment: Rovann você sabe fazer isso em WPF ?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda nunca fiz não, não tenho prática com WPF =/