# Como definir o espaço que uma string vai ocupar em C# / PDFsharp

Tags: c#, pdf

Gostaria de definir até onde a string vai ocupar o espaço. os valores (200,50) são referentes ao inicio do texto x= 200 y =50, os outros 2 valores eu não sei para oq serve, mesmo fazendo alguns testes.

```
textFormatter.DrawString("texto texto texto texto", fontTitulo,
PdfSharp.Drawing.XBrushes.Black,
new PdfSharp.Drawing.XRect(200,50, 10, 50));
```

Comment: normalmente, esses valores são X, Y, W, H... os dois últimos, largura e altura. No caso, do retângulo, não do texto

Comment: @RovannLinhalis isso, eu vejo o pessoal usando isso "(200,50,page.Height, page.Width)"  então acredito que isso é realmente é o limite, mas alterando o valor ele não altera esse limite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme podemos conferir no [código do PdfSharp](https://github.com/Lakerfield/PdfSharp/blob/master/PDFsharp/code/PdfSharp/PdfSharp.Drawing/XRect.cs#L56), o construtor é definido como: `public XRect(double x, double y, double width, double height)`.

Pensando nos dois eixos, X (Horizontal da esquerda pra direita) e Y (Vertical de cima pra baixo) temos um ponto X,Y que é o ponto inicial do retângulo.

Depois temos o valor W (Width / Largura) e H (Height / Altura) que são, respectivamente a largura e altura do retângulo.

Exemplo:

[image: Exemplo Rectangle]

Pelo que pude observar novamente no [código do PdfSharp](https://github.com/Lakerfield/PdfSharp/blob/master/PDFsharp/code/PdfSharp/PdfSharp.Drawing/XGraphics.cs#L3158), esse parâmetro só é utilizado pra calcular posição e alinhamento do texto.

E para você saber o tamanho que a string vai ocupar, você usa o método [`MeasureString`](https://github.com/Lakerfield/PdfSharp/blob/master/PDFsharp/code/PdfSharp/PdfSharp.Drawing/XGraphics.cs#L3325) que você você informa o texto, e a fonte e é retornado um objeto `XSize` com a largura e altura do texto.

Comment: Obrigado por sua ajuda, eu ja pensei em usar o método MeasureString, porem eu não posso "splitar" a palavra fora dos padrões do português, eu estava pensando em definir um espaço para adicionar texto, mas realmente ele só define posição e alinhamento do texto ):

Comment: certo, nessa resposta mostro como ir redimensionando o texto pra caber na tela se for interessante: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/254130/69359 De qualquer forma, se te ajudou não se esqueça de marcar como resposta. Obrigado